# parse form hidden field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a form_for form I have a hidden tag

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :receiver, :value => @post.user.email  %>
```

However when the form submits, the parameters look something like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",  "receiver"=>"{:value=>\"test@gmail.com\"}", "message"=>{"name"=>"asdfasf",...
```

and I want to extract test@gmail.com from my param in my controller like this:

```
  @string = params[:receiver]
```

and then pass it to my mailer.

Is there a way to convert params[:receiver] to just retrieve the value instead of the hash?

Comment: Yes, `@string = params[:receiver][:value]` (WARNING: will raise an error if `params[:receiver]` is not a Hash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your hidden input to:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :receiver, @post.user.email  %>
```

docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag